# Store input data on array

Tags: java

I am new to java and I would like to store inputted data on an array. My goal is to store the student's grades. So far, this is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
    public class GradesArray {
    public static void main (String[]args){
    int numStudents = 0;
    double grades[]= new double[0];
    double gradesStudent;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the number of students: ");
    numStudents = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1;i<=numStudents;i++){
        System.out.print("Enter the grade of student "+i+" : ");
            gradesStudent = in.nextInt();
            grades[i]=gradesStudent;
        }
    }
}
```

so my problem is. I get this error.

```
   `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at GradesArray.main(GradesArray.java:14)`
```

Comment: so what is your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You are creating an array of length 0 (`new double[0]`), you must use the inputed value `numStudents` to create the array:

```
double grades[] = new double[numStudents]; // You must specify the length inside []
```

Note that you will have to create the array **after** you have received the input in 
`numStudents = in.nextInt();`

Also, remember that indexes in Java starts in `0`, so your `for` loop should start with 0 and end in `numStudents - 1`. In other words `i < numStudents`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
    ... // modify the necessary
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 issues here.  First:

```
double grades[]= new double[0];
```

You have made the array size 0 (`new double[0];`).  However, you ask the user what size you want it to be.  So let's declare this variable when you get that first user input:

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of students: ");
numStudents = in.nextInt();
double grades[]= new double[numStudents];
```

Second your loop is wrong.  Java starts it's indexes for arrays at 0 (not 1).  Say you have size N array, then the indexes are 0 to N-1.  Change your loop from:

```
for (int i = 1;i<=numStudents;i++){
    //code
}
```

To:

```
for (int i = 0;i < numStudents;i++){
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you doing this:

```
double grades[]= new double[0];
                            ↑
```

This is **not** the default values of the array, it's its size, you should fix it to be the number of grades you want to store. You are getting the *exception* because your array can have only 0 elements.

Second, arrays are *zero-based* in Java. This line

```
for (int i = 1;i<=numStudents;i++){
```

Should be

```
for (int i = 0;i<numStudents;i++){
             ↑  ↑
```

Answer (score 0):

The below statement is problematic and it would create an array of 0 elements :

```
double grades[]= new double[0];
```

Instead use this  :

```
double grades[]= new double[numStudents];
```

Comment: I think you have added this line before you got numStudents from user...change the position where you initialize the array in the code.

numStudents = in.nextInt();
and then
double grades[]= new double[numStudents];

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your code:

```
double grades[]= new double[numStudents];
```

And change the `for` command to this

```
for (int i = 1;i < numStudents;i++){
}
```

loop was `outofbound`

Answer (score 0):

Compare with your code:

```
int numStudents = 0;
double gradesStudent;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number of students: ");
numStudents = in.nextInt();
double grades[]= new double[numStudents];
for (int i = 0;i<=numStudents-1;i++){
    System.out.print("Enter the grade of student "+(i+1)+" : ");
        gradesStudent = in.nextInt();
        grades[i]=gradesStudent;
    }
}
```